# javascript assigning variable inside a callback function return undefined

Tags: javascript

I have a simple script to play an audio like:

```
        var audio = new Audio(music)
        var music_duration
        audio.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
            var duration = audio.duration
            console.log(duration)
            music_duration = duration
        })

        console.log("checking duration")
        console.log(music_duration)
```

Here `music_duration` returns undefined..

while `duration` inside `addEventListener` gives duration of the music.

I am new to javascript ... What is wrong in here ??

Comment: this may be async call. needs to wait for response.

Comment: what is the solution ??

Comment: The duplicate question goes through the causes of the problem in detail and explains how this mechanism works and what you need to do.  You're unlikely to get a better explanation than the answers that already exist on that question.

Comment: You should also examine the "run-to-completion guarantee" principle

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log("checking duration")
console.log(music_duration)
```

will be executed before the *loadedmetadata* event is emitted.

You can check editing the script in this way:

```
    var audio = new Audio(music)
    var music_duration
    audio.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
        console.log('here')
        var duration = audio.duration
        console.log(duration)
        music_duration = duration
    })
    console.log('there')
    console.log("checking duration")
    console.log(music_duration)
```

You'll see `there` is printed before `here`.

Comment: what is the solution ??

Comment: @aryan you can move the code you need to execute after the callback in the callback itself - or in another function

Comment: You're merely describing  the symptom without addressing the cause. **Asynchronous control** flow and the **run-to-completion guarantee** are the cause of this behavior.